# Run questions and solutions in esami

Tags: esami

I am using the `esami` package to generate two files: (1) one that contains a single multiple choice question and (2) one file that contains the same question with the MCQ answer as well as the detailed solution.

I am having the following issues:  (1)  Where can I put additional solution text when writing the test questions so that it will appear when I generate the solutions file?  I suspect that `esami` may only be able to provide one letter answers to MCQs, but I wanted to be sure.

For example, here is the question mini-ma-03:

```
\newproblem{

\FPsetpar{a}{1}{4}\FPsetpar{b}{0}{9}

\item  $\angle A$ is a complement of $\angle B$.  If the measure of $\angle A$ is $\FPsv{a+b}^\circ$, what is the measure of $\angle B$?

\vspace{10 mm}

\begin{answers}{1}\bChoices[random]
    \Ans1 $\FPsv{90-(a+b)}^\circ$ \eAns
    \Ans0 $\FPsv{90+(a+b)}^\circ$ \eAns
    \Ans0 $\FPsv{180-(a+b)}^\circ$ \eAns  \eFreeze
    \Ans0 $\FPsv{180+(a+b)}^\circ$ \eAns
    \eChoices\end{answers}
}
```

I would like to provide a detailed solution in addition to the answer choice.  For example,

```
If $\angle A$ is complementary to $\angle B$, then $\angle A + \angle B = 90^{\circ}$, etc
```

would be inserted as red text in the solution version.

(2)  My second issue is I am manually running two files (one with solutions and one without).  My concern is that the variables a and b will not always match between the two since the variables are randomly generated.

Here is the MWE of the shell tex file used to run mini-ma-03:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[autopston,prova,twocolumns,xyz,nosolutions,fillb]{esami}

% +=============================+
% |         DEFINITIONS         |
% +=============================+

\def\examname{Practice ISEE: Exam 1}                                                                 
\def\numcompiti{1}%%% The number of the versions
\date{2013/07/23}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT YYYY/MM/DD
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{esame}
\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers

\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}

\randomi=\seme
\permuta

\begin{large}

\begin{test}
\begin{questions}
\esercizi{mini-ma-03}
\end{questions}
\end{test}

\closevers
}

\end{large}

\end{document}
```

Then I run this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[autopston,twocolumns,xyz,solutions,fillb]{esami}

% +=============================+
% |         DEFINITIONS         |
% +=============================+

\def\examname{Practice ISEE: Exam 1}                                                                 
\def\numcompiti{1}%%% The number of the versions
\date{2013/07/23}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT YYYY/MM/DD
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{esame}
\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers

\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}

\randomi=\seme
\permuta

\begin{large}

\begin{test}
\begin{questions}
\esercizi{mini-ma-03}
\end{questions}
\end{test}

\closevers
}

\end{large}

\end{document}
```

Can I run this in one file instead of two?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was able to solve the first issue pretty easily.  I simply added the text in the multiple choice answer.  If anyone could help out with running the two simulatenously, that would be great.

Comment: ok - never mind.  This solution shows up when I run the problem without solutions, so this won't be a great fix.

Answer (score 1):

1. the `esami` package does not allow to have solutions in MCQ. We are working on this issue, as it is a higly requested feature
2. it is not easy to produce both text and solutions from a single file. We have written a small template to do this for another similar package that we are testing, but the creation of the 2 files from a unique master needs a large use of `\write18` instructions (we have not found a better solution yet). We are working on this too. As for your problem of different values of the parameters `\a` and `\b`, the behaviour you report is very strange, as the seed does not depend on time, but on the number of the version and on the date, which are given data. I think that the problem is due to the option `prova` that you use in the no-solutions file and you don't use in the solutions file.

I noticed that you use in both files the option `fillb` which is not necessary as you don't have fill-in questions in your exam. Moreover, the option `autopston` is needed only if you have pstricks code in your file (it slows the compilation, so it is recommended not to use it if you don't use pstricks).